# DataSource declaration in Saxon XQJ API 

Tags: xslt, xquery, saxon

I need to write a program in order to implement XQuery in java using `saxon`. I am new to XQuery and saxon. I have downloaded `saxon-xqj-8.9.0.4.jar`and saxon9.jar and added both files to the classpath. the following is my simple test code

```
 import net.sf.saxon.javax.xml.xquery.XQConnection;
 import net.sf.saxon.javax.xml.xquery.XQException;
 import net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource;

 public class SaxonExtJavaObject {
     public String f() {

    return "Some string";
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws XQException {

        SaxonXQDataSource xqds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
        XQConnection xqc = xqds.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connected");
}

}
```

The problem is that it gives the following exception

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.saxon.Configuration.makeSchemaAwareConfiguration(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)Lnet/sf/saxon/Configuration;
at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource.<init>(SaxonXQDataSource.java:34)
at SaxonExtJavaObject.main(SaxonExtJavaObject.java:17)
```

I think the issue is because of `SaxonXQDataSource xqds = new SaxonXQDataSource();` but I cannot solve it, Can someone help em please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAR file saxon-xqj-8.9.0.4.jar is part of Saxon 8.9.0.4, whereas your saxon9.jar must come from release 9.0 or later. You can't mix different JAR files from different Saxon releases.

At some stage, I forget when, the XQJ code was combined into the main Saxon JAR file, so you no longer need a separate JAR. The reason it was originally separate was that it had dependencies (on the JDK) that were not present in the main JAR file.

Comment: I deleted the  saxon-xqj-8.9.0.4.jar from the class path, so now I just have saxon9.jar . but it doesn't recognize any of the imports. any idea please?